# Hibernate query to get Data from Oracle table inserted in last 5 mins

Tags: oracle, hibernate, date, hibernate-criteria

I have a table called EMPLOYEE, and in that table there is column called CREATE_DATE which is of type DATE.

And I'm using Hibernate to retrieve the records of employee inserted in the last 5 minutes.

Is it possible to retrieve the records based on CREATE_DATE column !

If possible how do we write a hibernate criteria for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract five minutes from the current date/time:

```
SELECT *
  FROM EMPLOYEE
  WHERE CREATE_DATE > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where CREATE_DATE > sysdate - 1/24/60*5
```